# SQL query to get students who have enrolled in English or Urdu course but not in both

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Query should return Naveed Rizwan Fayaz and Ahmed Name.

SQL query for students who have enrolled in English or Urdu course but not in both.

```
declare @Student table(sid int identity(1, 1), sname varchar(250))
declare @Course table(cid int identity(1, 1), cname varchar(250))

declare @StudentCourse table(cid int, sid int)
insert into @Student(sname)

select 'Mehboob' union all --1
select 'Rahim' union all -- 2 
select 'Naveed' union all --3 
select 'Rizwan' union all --4
select 'Fayaz' union all --5
select 'Ahmed' -- 6

insert into @Course(cname)
select 'English' union all
select 'Urdu' 


insert into @StudentCourse(sid ,cid)
select 1,1 union all
select 2,1 union all
select 3,1 union all
select 4,1 union all
select 5,2 union all
select 6,2 union all
select 1,2 union all
select 2,2
```

Comment: And what would be the expected result?

Comment: Query should return Naveed Rizwan Fayaz and Ahmed Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sid, max(cid)
from StudentCourse 
group by sid
having count(*)=1
```

Answer (score 2):

I kept practicing and finally i did it by this query do you guys have any other in your mind.

```
select 
    s.*, count(1) as TotalEnrolledCourses 
from  
    @Student s
inner join 
    @StudentCourse sc on s.sid = sc.sid
where 
    sc.cid in (1,2)
group by 
    s.sid, sname 
having 
    TotalEnrolledCourses  = 1
```

Comment: This should be `HAVING count(1) = 1`.

Comment: Correct me if I be mistaken, but isn't the condition `sc.cid in (1,2)` _not_ an XOR...meaning it means course 1 _OR_ course 2?

Answer (score 1):

From here you can get complete information of a student with one registered course i.e Name and ID etc.

```
SELECT  s.*
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN (select sid, max(cid)
            from StudentCourse 
            group by sid
            having count(*)=1
           ) sc ON s.sid=sc.sid
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to solve your problem:

```
SELECT
    s.sid,
    s.sname
FROM @StudentCourse sc
INNER JOIN @Student s
    ON s.sid = sc.sid
WHERE
    sc.cid IN(1, 2)
GROUP BY
    s.sid, s.sname
HAVING
    (
        SUM(CASE WHEN sc.cid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN sc.cid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ) = 1
```